# Create React App Error when trying to run command npx create react app: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, windows, create-react-app

When I try to run a simple `npx create-react-app` i received this error:

```
D:\>npx create-react-app abc
npx: installed 67 in 4.255s

Creating a new React app in D:\abc.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\Gilang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\17768\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\Gilang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\17768\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:407:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\Gilang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\17768\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:359:10)
    at C:\Users\Gilang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\17768\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:485:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting abc/ from D:\
Done.
```

I'm using windows 10 version 20H2 and node v14.15.4.

I've also made an issue on the official `create-react-app` github [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10670)

Comment: Try with a global install `npm install -g create-react-app` and then use `create-react-app abc` and see if it works

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I'm still getting the same exact error. @TarunLalwani

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I'm using `node v14.15.4.`  @TarunLalwani

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with `node v14.15.4` and `npx create-react-app abc`.
I recommend you uninstall node.js and install it again and retry.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is issue with write permission.

Try running `npx create-react-app myapp` from cmd with elevated permissions, i.e., run cmd as Admin and then try to create / scaffold your app.

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me, I just reinstalled `create-react-app` with the following and it fixed the detected issues:

```
npm install create-react-app
npm audit fix --force
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: npm audit fix --force .. did work for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess this error occurred because of unsupported globally install `create-react-app`.

There is a tiny point in this problem, and it is there is global installs of `create-react-app` are no longer supported. So at the first, run this command

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then  install `create-react-app` in this way

```
npm install create-react-app
```

Then create your react app

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
   npm cache clear --force
```

and retry again.

As per the website https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/, it is mentioned :

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g >create->react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create->react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the >latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I was having the same issue. TBH I didn't know what cause it either but after running through some websites and YouTube tutorials I finally discovered the way to solve this problem.

First of all, you need to know what best node version that work on your PC or laptop base on what system it used.

Second, you go to run administration by clicking windows <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, write `%tempt%` and delete all the files inside but skip those that can not be deleted, then once again write `prefetch` on search bar in run administration and also delete all the files inside just like before.

After that open `Node.js command prompt` (you can find it on search explore bar) but don't forget to already installed the `Node.js`. Click on the arrow and choose **run as administrator** with that the command prompt interface would be open.

Notice that the default writing already in `C:\Windows\System32>`, so you need to make the folder inside `System32` section in windows. Let's say you make this `examplereactjs` ( Make sure using non-cap letters, because I don't know why mine won't run if I used caps letter), after that, you can make your `npx` just like usual so it would be like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd examplereactjs
```

Press enter, it would be like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32\examplereactjs>npx create-react-app examplereactjs
```

Press enter, and wait for couple minutes. You can start with `npm start` to open the local host browser.

This method works for me and I found it by accident actually. If this doesn't work for you, I don't know what else can. I'm still a newbie in this field and I have no idea what would cause if you messing with run administration, well I'm just here to help. Anyway let me know if this method works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

if reinstall create-react-app is fail and also you already try to run cmd with admin privileges but still not fix it. Try to disable your antivirus and run it once again, work like a charm for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On running this command, if this error occur then try to disable antivirus or simply when pop up comes of antivirus then click on the link in the antivirus pop up then there is no error.
Work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same issue, try to use "npm audit fix --force".

Comment: Any insight into why this might fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just Uninstall the antivirus from your system!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my think, it may be caused by a vaccine program blocking access to the network.

Sometimes a free antivirus program is installed without user consent. And as these are executed in real time, even simple installation commands used by developers are often recognized as access to malicious code.

If you have a recently installed antivirus, uninstall it and run 'npx create-reate-app my-app' again at the terminal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

uninstalled your antivirus, and most likely it will work. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It happened with me too

> You just need to uninstalled the antivirus eg window security->Virus & threat protection then go to Manage settings ->disabled the real-time protection if it is disable and you get declaimer of **You're having another antivirus** then search for RVC endpoint or RAV Antivirus and uninstalled it and then this will enabled  real-time protection and disable it and then try `npx create-react-app app-name`
> hope this works and if doesn't let me know. Thanks

[The exact same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sVkk.png)