# Creating app in ReactJs does not work using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm

So I'm trying to learn reactJS by following the docs, I have already install node.js and npm but the problem is that when I run

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

gives me this error
[image]
I don't what is going on, any Idea?

Comment: which node version you are using ?

Comment: @sojin node.js 16.13.0 LTS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558006/create-react-app-error-when-trying-to-run-command-npx-create-react-app-spawn-un

Comment: do you get the same error without npx? (Installing cra globally)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this worked for me:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install node
npm install -g yarn
yarn cache clean
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: didn't work for me:(

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was that I have active a antivirus, so I add in the exceptions that yarn is not a danger.
[image]