# what is error create-react-app Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what is showing error showing on reactjs  Aborting installation. Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:?

```
Aborting installation.
    Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
    Error: spawn UNKNOWN
        at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
        at Object.spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
        at spawn (D:\ankit\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
        at D:\ankit\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at install (D:\ankit\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
        at D:\ankit\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
      errno: -4094,
      code: 'UNKNOWN',
      syscall: 'spawn'
    }
    
    Deleting generated file... package.json
    Deleting react-app/ from D:\ankit
    Done.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558006/create-react-app-error-when-trying-to-run-command-npx-create-react-app-spawn-un any of this helps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create React App Error when trying to run command npx create react app: spawn UNKNOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558006/create-react-app-error-when-trying-to-run-command-npx-create-react-app-spawn-un)

Comment: I have already tried but I get no problem solved..any suggestions for me!