# any suggestions on how i can solve this error?

Tags: reactjs, command, create-react-app

I am trying to create a react app but I keep getting this error.
any suggestions on how I can solve this?

here is the command screen :

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1556]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Raad>cd desktop

C:\Users\Raad\Desktop>cd react-redux

C:\Users\Raad\Desktop\react-redux> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Raad\Desktop\react-redux\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
at spawn (C:\Users\Raad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
at C:\Users\Raad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
at new Promise ()
at install (C:\Users\Raad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
at C:\Users\Raad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\Raad\Desktop\react-redux
Done.

C:\Users\Raad\Desktop\react-redux>

Comment: See if anything from this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558006/create-react-app-error-when-trying-to-run-command-npx-create-react-app-spawn-un

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? The title of your question should not be so generic