# Evertime I try to run my react app it gives me error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whenever I try to run
`npx create-react-app my-app`
it gives me error.
I got stuck here can anyone help?

```
PS E:\ALI\Eziline work\React work> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in E:\ALI\Eziline work\React work\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:713:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\Syed Taha Ali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\Syed Taha Ali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\Syed Taha Ali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)
    at C:\Users\Syed Taha Ali\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from E:\ALI\Eziline work\React work
Done.
```

This is the error I always face.

Comment: pls, check this thread. ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558006/create-react-app-error-when-trying-to-run-command-npx-create-react-app-spawn-un/72879257#72879257```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

**install node.js**

if you already installed that  clear your cache using

`npm cache clean --force` and try again

Comment: Hey. Mr. Charan. I have did what you said but it still does'nt help out

Comment: Try with a global install npm install -g create-react-app and then use create-react-app my-app and see if it works